# Dynamodb Request exceeds more than provided throughput

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have a Provisioned write capacity as 15,To write 1kb/sec of file into db it takes 1 write capacity.Having this 15 write capacity if i send 60kb data to insert.Does it take more time or does it throw an exception due to lack of Write capacity units

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB would throw an exception with **HTTP status code 400 (Bad Request)**.

> If your application's read or write requests exceed the provisioned
>   throughput for a table, DynamoDB might throttle that request. When
>   this happens, the request fails with an HTTP 400 code (Bad Request),
>   accompanied by a ProvisionedThroughputExceededException. The AWS SDKs
>   have built-in support for retrying throttled requests. However, you
>   might want to consider using exponential backoff logic in your error
>   handling code. For more information, see Error Retries and Exponential
>   Backoff.

[Error Retries and Exponential Backoff](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.Errors.html#Programming.Errors.RetryAndBackoff)

Answer (score 0):

Your request is **likely** to go through because of **Burst Capacity**. Here is how [AWS Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/GuidelinesForTables.html#GuidelinesForTables.Bursting) describes it:

> DynamoDB provides some flexibility in the per-partition throughput provisioning.
>   When you are not fully utilizing a partition's throughput, DynamoDB retains a portion of your unused capacity for later bursts of throughput usage.  DynamoDB currently retains up five minutes (300 seconds) of unused read and write capacity.  During an occasional burst of read or write activity, these extra capacity units can be consumed very quickly—even faster than the per-second provisioned throughput capacity that you've defined for your table.

For instance, if you use 14 of your provisioned throughput of 15 Write Capacity Units for five minutes, you get a burst capacity of 300 Write Capacity Units. However, this isn't something your application should rely on. AWS DynamoDB documentation also states:

> However, do not design your application so that it depends on burst capacity being available at all times: DynamoDB can and does use burst capacity for background maintenance and other tasks without prior notice.

This is also worth mentioning from the documentation:

> **Note**
>   In the future, these details of burst capacity may change.

To answer the specific question that you ask: If a 60 Kb write request will go through at a provisioned throughput of 15 Kb/s. Very, very likely yes. I hope that it is a one off "retriable" request and not a regular behaviour since Burst Capacity is meant exactly for the former type of situation: Sudden spikes in throughput usage that exceed the maximum provisioned throughput for short periods of time.